# MIP formulation for graph planarity test

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, graphs

In [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/48099/integer-linear-program-formulation-of-planarity), it was asked wether a MIP formulation exists to test for a graph's planarity. The inputs are the graph's nodes and edges, and the output would be a certificate which guarantees that the graph is, or is not, planar.

The python package NetworkX provides a [method](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/algorithms/planarity.html#is_planar) which does exactly this, but it is not based on linear programming. The source code provides the following references:

- Ulrik Brandes: [The Left-Right Planarity Test](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.217.9208) (2009)
- Takao Nishizeki, Md Saidur Rahman: Planar graph drawing, Lecture Notes Series on Computing: Volume 12 (2004)

Some ideas:

- [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Plane_graphs) ($n-m+f=2$); but this depends on how the nodes (and edges) are organized in space, which is not part of the input data.
- $G$ planar $\implies m\le 3n-6$; but this does not cover all cases, it can be a tool to prove that a graph is not planar, but is useless the otherway around.
- There is a relationship between planar graphs and [book embeddings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_embedding) (see this great [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qw2Pl_Nk3CA) from Numberphile for a recent breakthrough in graph theory on the subject), but not sure it helps.
- Other characterizations of planar graphs are mentioned on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Planarity_criteria), such as [Whitney's planarity criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney%27s_planarity_criterion) or [Mac Lane's planarity criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Lane%27s_planarity_criterion). These might be interesting.

To this day, the question has not been answered. I find the question interesting from a modeling point of view and am curious wheter it can be answered **with a MIP**.

Comment: My best bet would be that you can check if the graph has $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as a minor, which is equivalent to planarity by Wagner's theorem. Checking if $H$ is a minor of $G$, for fixed $H$, seems doable, you have to find $|V(H)|$ vertex-disjoint connected subgraphs in $G$, each representing a vertex of $H$, such that there is at least one edge between parts corresponding to adjacent vertices of $H$. Disclaimer, I have not checked any details.

Comment: As far as I checked Euler's theorem, It is not correct for the space with dimension $\mathbb{R}^2$. As the graph was planar. (I am not aware of if there exists a counterpart).